# Angular 2.0 'require' is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

In attempting to run the Angular 2.0 Quickstart for Typescript in Visual Studio 2015 from here: [Angular 2.0 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
I have had quite a bit of trouble.  After getting beyond the Typescript issues by putting the settings from tsconfig.json into the project properties xaml I am getting a runtime error "require is undefined" I have tried to use IE 11, IE Edge and Chrome 48.0. Rather than reposting the code here I will just say that it is cut and pasted from the examples with the exception of the following typing being added at the top of main.ts which seems to silence other error messages:

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
```

I have seen this issue discussed in several older posts with no solution being found.

Comment: What are you using ... systemjs, commonjs? Can you put the html includes and the package.json?

Comment: <TypeScriptModuleKind>CommonJS</TypeScriptModuleKind>

Comment: seems like you have not included the commonjs file as html includes. Can you update the html code?

Answer (score 0):

Download SystemJs library & refer in html

```
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
```

mentioned in quick start.

SystemJS is for loading application and library modules.

Comment: Indeed it is mentioned.  I have that reference in place as I copied the html exactly from the example except I needed to add <!DOCTYPE html> at the top. The node_modules folder is straight from the current distribution. The problem remains.

Comment: @jerrylan any luck on the issue?